# Argument labels (forItem:,inSection:) do not match any available overloads

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3

I have a following snippet of code, that i am using for collection view category.

```
func indexPathForCategory(category: Category) -> NSIndexPath
    {
        let section = sections.index(of: category.section)
        var item = 0
        for (index, currentCategory) in categoriesForSection(index: section!).enumerated() {
            if currentCategory === category {
                item = index
                break
            }
        }
        return NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: section!)
    }
```

On the return statement, i get the error as Argument labels (forItem:,inSection:) do not match any available overloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSIndexPath(item:section:)` instead.